# Information Rights Management (IRM) causing issues in files hosted on Microsoft Teams

Tags: security, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I was hoping to find some answers to this issue of IRM. I've noticed some word documents with sensitivity labels (highly confidential) we were experimenting with and hosted on 'files' on Teams do not open in browser but would rather ask that we 'Edit in Desktop App'. Users on Mac OS unlike windows are not able to open the files at all no matter what.

Any chance there are links or sources from Microsoft known for this very specific issue? I'd be extremely grateful for some feedback.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZMIF.jpg)